# Executing remote script locally using subprocess - Remote script uses vars from ~/.profile

Tags: python, bash, unix, subprocess

I am executing a script that resides on the remote server.
This bash script makes use of a variable.
This variable is defined in ~/.profile.
For this purpose lets say it

```
$MYVAR=/a/b/c
```

So on remote server, or even ssh to remote and I execute

```
echo $MYVAR returns /a/b/c as you would expect.
```

But if I execute the remote script locally using python subprocess, the script fails. It fails as the script uses the $MYVAR which translates as soemthing incorrect.

This is because I am executing it via SSH, the ~./profile must not be getting loaded and instead it is using some other profile. 
see here https://superuser.com/questions/207200/how-can-i-set-environment-variables-for-a-remote-rsync-process/207262#207262

Here is the command executed from a python script

```
ssh = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', '%s' % env.host, 'cd /script/dir | ./myscript arg1 arg2'],shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

My question is how can I run a script locally, that will ssh to remote, load the users ~/.profile then execute a bash script.

Comment: no idea how `$MYVAR` is being used in your code, does it in `./myscript`?

Comment: `cd something | somecommand` does nothing useful because `cd` does not produce anything useful on standard output.  What are you *actually* trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you looking for `['ssh', 'remote', 'cd dir; myvar="{}" somecommand arg1 arg2'.format(shlex.quote(os.environ['MYVAR']))`?

Comment: I want to ssh to remote, change directory to where the script exists. Then run the script. $MYVAR isnt used in my code at all. The remote script uses it. That remote scripts exits because $MYVAR isnt what it should be. The weird thing is(for me anyway) is that when you run the echo $MYVAR on the remote box, it returns what IS expected. So where is it getting this other value from. Thats what I dont understand.

Comment: @georgexsh the remote script uses a variable that is defined in ~/.profile
I realise that when I ssh to the remote server, the ./.profile is not the one being used hence why that variable is different.

So i am wondering what is the best way to ssh to remote, source ~/.profile and excute the bash script

Comment: @Nanotron try this https://superuser.com/questions/306530/run-remote-ssh-command-with-full-login-shell

Comment: I will try that too and as another option b) i have created another script which i will scp to server and source the .profile and exec the remote script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution for this was to create a sort of wrapper script like so

```
#!/bin/bash
. /users/me/.profile

cd /dir/where/script/exists/

exec script LIVE "$@"
```

So now then create a method in the python script to scp the wrapper script to tmp dir

```
scp wrapper user@remote:/tmp
```

Now ssh command in the question becomes

```
subprocess.Popen(['ssh', '%s' % env.host, env.installPatch],shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

env.installPatch translates to:

```
cd /tmp; ./wrapper 'patch_name'
```

Now the .profile is loaded and the patch script has the correct variable vals.
With using exec I get all the output back from the patch o/p and can write to file.

This was the cleanest solution for my case.

Answer (score 1):

you can use paramiko module to run the scripts on remote server from locally.

http://www.paramiko.org/

Once installed , you can run the command as shown in example below

```
import paramiko
command=" 'ssh', '%s' % env.host, 'cd /script/dir | ./myscript arg1 arg2' "
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('192.18.1.26',port=22,username='root',password='defassult') #This will connect to remote server
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command(command)  #This will execute the command on remote server
output=stdout.readlines()
print '\n'.join(output)
```

Comment: Hi, yes I realsie there were modules available but Im trying to keep this as simple as possible for others to use this script. i.e. for this purpose, only standard library modules can be used.